# how to insert a node before the last node in linked list?

Tags: java, methods, linked-list

I am having trouble creating a method that adds the item before the last element in java. I already have the code for adding the last element in a linked list.

How should I implement `addBeforeLast`?

```
public class LinkedList {
    Node first;
    int size = 0;

    public void addLast(int item) {
        // If the list is empty, just create a node and make it
        // the first.
        if(first == null) {
            first = new Node(item, null);
        } else {
           // Otherwise, find the last node
            Node current = first;
            // Stop when current's next is null: that's how
            // we know it's the last element.
            while(current.next != null) {
                current = current.next;
            }
             Node prev = current;
            // At this point, current is the last node.
            // Make it point to a new node that will contain
            // the given item.
            current.next = new Node(item, prev);
        }
        size++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  You have not actually asked a question, just shown some code that does not work.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Have a try like this:

```
public void addBeforeLast(int a) {
    if (first == null) throw new IllegalStateException("There is no last node"); // we cannot addBeforeLast when there is no last;
    if (first.next == null) { // when only single node, we have to update first;
        first = new Node(a, first);
        return;
    }
    Node p = first;
    while (p.next.next != null) p = p.next; // p.next will be the last node now;
    p.next = new Node(a, p.next);
}
```

The Node will have a constructor as:

```
    public Node(int theVal, Node theNext) {
        this.val = theVal;
        this.next = theNext;
    }
```

By the way, if you insist to add new node even when there is no node for `addBeforeLast`.  You can use this method:

```
public void addBeforeLast(int a) {
    if (first == null || first.next == null) { // we have to update first;
        first = new Node(a, first);
        return;
    }
    Node p = first;
    while (p.next.next != null) p = p.next; // p.next will be the last node now;
    p.next = new Node(a, p.next);
}
```